# What is the meaning of "integral point"?

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, terminology, euclidean-geometry, combinatorial-game-theory

While reading this paper (http://cowles.econ.yale.edu/P/cd/d04b/d0473.pdf) I encountered the concept of "integral point", used first in definition 5.1, on page 34. Does anybody know more details about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context it simply means a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with integer coordinates, i.e., a lattice point of the lattice defined by his unit vectors $e^i$.

Answer (score 2):

This is an English question:

*Integral (noun). Of, pertaining to, or being an integer.*